# SNMP scraping returned HTTP status 500 Internal Server Error on Prometheus

Tags: snmp, network-monitoring, mikrotik, prometheus, scraping

I installed Prometheus and SNMP exporter on Ubuntu Server, then configuring for scraping with

```
/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml


  - job_name: 'Mikrotik'
static_configs:
  - targets:
    - 10.10.106.210  # Mikrotik device.
metrics_path: /snmp
params:
  module: [mikrotik]
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    target_label: __param_target
  - source_labels: [__param_target]
    target_label: instance
  - target_label: __address__
    replacement: 172.16.9.231:9116
```

But Prometheus showing target device with error server returned HTTP status 500 Internal Server Error

Everything is default, no other config made.

Manually requesting SNMP exporter show

```
An error has occurred while serving metrics:

error collecting metric Desc{fqName: "snmp_error", help: "Error scraping target", constLabels: {module="mikrotik"}, variableLabels: []}: error walking target 10.10.106.210: error in unmarshalResponse: expected a sequence when unmarshalling a VB, got 25
```

Can someone help me? Do i need provide more info?

Comment: blackbox_exporter provides additional information if additional parameter `debug=true` is passed in manual request. I don't this being mention in snmp_export, but i think this worth a try.

Comment: Additionally, consider this post: https://www.robustperception.io/using-snmpbulkwalk-to-debug-snmp_exporter-issues/